# c# using dc:date namespace

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, rss

I have an RSS feed that works fine as is. I'm trying to add another item "dc:date" using the code i already have, how can I make this work? Also, for some reason i'm getting an extra paragraph row generated after the the title, not sure why.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void ProcessRSSItem(string rssURL)
{
    WebRequest myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://feeds.feedburner.com/HIGHTIMESMagazine");
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream rssStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();

    XmlDocument rssDoc = new XmlDocument();
    rssDoc.Load(rssStream);

    XmlNodeList rssItems = rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");

    string title = "";
    string link = "";
    string description = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 && i < rssItems.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlNode rssDetail;

        rssDetail = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("title");
        if (rssDetail != null)
        {
            title = rssDetail.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            title = "";
        }
        rssDetail = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("link");
        if (rssDetail != null)
        {
            link = rssDetail.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            link = "";
        }
        rssDetail = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("description");
        if (rssDetail != null)
        {
            description = rssDetail.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            description = "";
        }
        Response.Write("<h6><b><a href='"+ link +"'target='new'>" + title + "</a></b></h6>");
        Response.Write("<p>" + description + "</P>");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have to use XmlDocument? LINQ to XML makes namespace handling *really* simple.

Comment: I'm to new to this and didn't know there was another way to simplify my RSS code.  I'm transitioning from Sys-Admin to Developer.  You wouldn't happen to have an example?

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx - and learn LINQ to XML from documentation rather than just examples. Also note that currently you're not disposing of your `WebResponse`, which can lead to problems - use a `using` statement to do so.